# Checking whether a string conforms to a printf-style format

Tags: java

I'm developing a program which needs to find files from across multiple folders based on a pattern. Previously, I've been working under the assumption that each filename consists of a prefix followed by an underscore and a number, but this is no longer the case. I need some way of allowing a user to enter a pattern (probably in printf format), and checking whether strings in a list conform to the given pattern, like `test_%d.tif`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ask them pattern in regexp format and match filename against it.

Comment: My users don't know regex well enough to use it, but I could just convert it from printf to regex in code. Thanks for the idea!